# Saving all local MySQL operations to replicate them to an online database

Tags: mysql, database

I have two databases right now: one in local and one in the cloud.

I was wondering if it would be possible to save all the MySQL DML commands/operations that I perform in my local database somewhere (e.g. local file system, or even a new separate table for it in the database) so I can then process all of those commands, one by one and replicate them to my database in the cloud?

The reason is that I'm using my database in the cloud as the **backup database** and so my local database and my online database should be in sync.

If what I'm thinking isn't possible, is there another way around this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Replication or Use canal may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a feature. It's called the [Binary Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html). There's no need to explain further, because it has full documentation. Visit the link I just provided.

It's probably not easy to use replication in your case, because it would require your remote MySQL Server to connect to your local MySQL as a client, and I expect that's not possible because of firewalls or NAT.

But you could collect your local binary logs, and upload them periodically, and then use the same technique as point-in-time recovery to apply them to the remote MySQL server. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery-binlog.html